# Grabbing data from other workbooks using wildcards ERROR

Tags: excel, vba, wildcard

I know it might be a silly mistake but I tried many ways of doing that and none of them worked.

I have this code in place for grabbing data from other excel sheets in a folder and pasting it in a master folder. The issue pops up when I try to use wildcards to look for files where part of the name is variable. In the example below, the file name is `Stock_RTC_17.02.2019.xlsx`.

However, excel returns an error that the file is not found in the folder for the code below, even though you can see **it has found the correct file name**. Anyone got a clue on what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

```
Sub copytest() 'Procedure for retrieving data from the sourcefiles

    Dim wbTarget, wbSource As Workbook
    Dim target As Object
    Dim pathSource As String
    Dim xlApp As Application

    'path where the data source folders are located (please keep all of them in the same directory)
    pathSource = "C:\Users\vferraz\Desktop\crm stock\RAPOARTE IMPORTANTE\18.02\Rapoarte pentru Handsets\"
    Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Stock RTC
    Dim FileName As String

    FileName = Dir(pathSource & "Stock_RTC_*.xlsx", vbNormal)

    Set wbSource = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName)

    wbSource.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy
    wbSource.Close
    Set target = wbTarget.Sheets("Stock Aberon GW TKR")
    target.UsedRange.Clear
    Range("A1").Select
    target.Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think pathSource is not the current working directory, so you should write:

```
Set wbSource = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(pathSource & FileName)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the path when you try to open the workbook.

```
Set wbSource = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(pathSource & FileName)
```